# Maven script to install jdk and set enviornment variable

Tags: maven, java-8

I want to install jdk1.8 using maven script and want to set enviornment variable as well for MAC and Linux.

Can it is posible using maven script if yes please let me know what script I need to write?

Answer (score 4):

We can not install Jdk using maven script as maven is jdk based tool to run maven script jdk must be install on your system